# CLLocationManager sometimes returns (0, 0) coordinate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cllocationmanager

I am using CLLocationManager to get user coordinates. Then I send it to our Web API to get some information back. But recently, API started returning error caused by zero coordinates. In error reports I found out that a small chunk of users started getting (0, 0) coordinates from the CLLocationManager. The point is we didn't change anything concerning geolocation. I am a bit surprised because this part has been working flawlessly for 2 years by now.

Geolocation code is standard:

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    //Started returning (0, 0) sometimes
}
```

I googled the problem but had no results. Any guesses?

Comment: how you are accesing location..?

Comment: We also sometimes have this problem (just very few of our users have this issue, but for them it happens quite often). Have you managed to understand why this was happening and how to fix it ? Did testing the horizontalAccuracy work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I'd check for the Accuracy, see the Apple Documentation for that (@Discussion), the value can indicate if your location is valid / invalid

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let location = locations.last, location.horizontalAccuracy >= 0 else {
        return

    }
}
```

Doku:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423599-horizontalaccuracy
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423550-verticalaccuracy

P.S.: I'd never access the locations with an index like 'locations[0]' tends to produce errors -> guard the last location like I did and you should be fine.

Hope this helps. (:

Comment: It's a nice bit of information I didn't know about, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this tip, but I wanted to note that checking `horizontalAccuracy` didn't work in my testing. Instead, I'm `return`ing immediately from `didUpdateLocations` if `coordinate.latitude == 0` since I don't believe that would ever be valid. Since I don't call `stopUpdatingLocation()` until I have a valid location, `didUpdateLocations` will be called multiple times, usually once, but up to 4 times in my (limited) testing, which seems acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Edward use this code for Location. add also add the key in info.plist

**NSAppTransportSecurity, 
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription,
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**

```
//  AppDelegate.swift

 import UIKit


 @UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var addressString : String!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var lat : Double!
var long : Double!
var cordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
var searchLocationCordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
var currentLocation: CLLocation!


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

checkLocation()

}

 func checkLocation() {
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedWhenInUse
    {
        print("requestingautorization")
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    } else {
        print("startupdatinglocation")
    }
}




 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    cordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude,longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    print(cordinates)

}
```